# Why is the velocity of my rigid body in OnCollisionEnter always zero?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

My object must explode when the player touches it or when it collides at a low speed.

The problem I'm having is that its speed becomes zero when the floor collides for example and then the `OnCollisionEnter` event is called, it is already late and never fulfills the condition.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong or what I should do to fix this?

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.magnitude));
    if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.magnitude) >= detonationImpactVelocity)
        Explosion(200);

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        Explosion (600);

}
```

I came up with this but I guess there must be a better way to do it.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.magnitude) >= detonationImpactVelocity)
        explosionSpeedAchieved = true;
    else
        explosionSpeedAchieved = false;
    Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.magnitude));
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    Debug.Log(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.magnitude));
    if (explosionSpeedAchieved)
        Explosion(200);

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        Explosion (600);

}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to wrap magnitudes in an absolute value function - they're non-negative by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check instead the collision's relative velocity:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    Debug.Log(collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude);
    if (collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude >= detonationImpactVelocity)
        Explosion(200);

    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        Explosion (600);
}
```

On a side note, it would be more efficient to check the `sqrMagnitude` against the square of `detonationImpactVelocity` to avoid an unnecessary sqrt calculation.

Comment: "On a side note, it would be more efficient to check the sqrMagnitude against the square of detonationImpactVelocity to avoid an unnecessary sqrt calculation."  I do not understand the idea well

Comment: For example: 

`if (collision.relativeVelocity.sqrMagnitude >= detonationImpactVelocity * detonationImpactVelocity)` or possibly `if (collision.relativeVelocity.sqrMagnitude >= sqrDetonationImpactVelocity)` if you precalculate `sqrDetonationImpactVelocity` in `Start`. This is because calculating `collision.relativeVeolocity.sqrMagnitude` is simpler (and faster) for the computer to do than calculating `collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the relative linear velocity from the Collision object itself:

```
if (Mathf.Abs(other.relativeVelocity.magnitude) >= detonationImpactVelocity)
```

See also: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html

Comment: Aww, you just beat me to it